# There's something wrong with my Mac mini, but I don't know what

Tags: finder, time-machine, external-disk, mac-mini, big-sur

I have a Mac mini (2018) which used to behave reliably. But since I upgraded it to Big Sur, its behaviour has become erratic. Something is wrong, but I can't get a handle on it.

**Symptoms**

It all started when I upgraded to Big Sur from Catalina. The upgrade failed, but I managed to work around it, and all subsequent upgrades upto and including 11.2.3 were successful.

Then, last week, I tried to upgrade to 11.3.1. This failed and it threw me into Recovery. Repeatedly. So I saved what I still needed onto a USB stick and then did a clean install of 11.2.3, which went without a hitch.

I have been trying for some time (even before the upgrade to 11.3.1) to get Time Machine working on an external disk. I would like to backup the Mac mini itself and two other users' data on this disk.

I acquired a StarTech S352BU313R and installed two WD 6TB disks, which form a single RAID 1 volume. I created partitions for the Mac mini and for each of the two users. I then set up Time Machine for the Mac mini. This worked OK for a few hours, but then the weirdness set in.

Time Machine fails and presents the following message:
[image: Time Machine error]

Time Machine deselects the backup disk, which means that no further attempts are made to perform a backup:
[image: Back disk deselected]

As if this were not enough, Finder starts acting strangely. Selecting any Finder object (e.g. a window) results in the dreaded spinning ball and the Finder popup indicates that the Finder is unresponsive. In this state, System Preferences sometimes freezes in sympathy with the Finder, though Terminal and other apps still work. Eventually (at least 15 minutes later) Finder recovers (until the next time...). Relaunching the Finder has no immediate effect: I guess whatever causes the freeze also prevents relaunching.

This is my configurations seen from `diskutil` (the Mac mini's TM disk is called `LAN Server TM`):
[image: Disk configuration in diskutil]

When the Finder is in the above unresponsive state, `diskutil` hangs longer than I am patient, and does not get round to displaying `/dev/disk3`, `/dev/disk4` or `/dev/disk5`.

Finally, I often have to resort to restarting the Mac mini to get out of the unresponsive Finder state. Trying to restart the machine often leaves just the Dock on the screen and nothing happens. However, if I right-click on the Finder icon and select `Relaunch`, the restart continues immediately.

After the clean install of 11.3.1, I had to reinstall UniFi Controller 6.1.71 on the Mac mini along with its backed-up data. This now also behaves erratically, which it didn't before: it keeps on going offline and complaining about my UniFi devices being unreachable, but when I try to login to the controller, it is the controller that is unreachable.

**Steps Taken**

I had a long exchange with StarTech's support, but we were unable to identify where the problem lay. Then it disappeared for no apparent reason. That was before I upgraded MacOS to 11.3.1. Since the upgrade, the problem has reappeared.

I have used a different pair of disks in the StarTech enclosure and I have done scans on the 6TB disks, which are new and show no errors.

Today, I ran the MacOS diagnostics on the Mac mini (boot with `D`). No problem was identified.

**How to Proceed?**

This I where I would appreciate some help. My first assumption is that I have done something stupid. Attaching a StarTech RAID 1 might fall into this category :-)

To me it looks like something going wrong in software. The problem is not immediate, which I tend to expect from hardware. Also, I find the behaviour of the Finder suspicious.

I threw in the UniFi Controller into the symptoms list. But could it be something more general in Big Sur that is causing all these problems?

However, I don't know what I should be looking at or for. I'm lost. Anybody got any ideas or tips please?

**Addendum**

Based on the helpful feedback that I have received (see below) I can add some further information.

The TM backup failed again with the same error as above (error while creating the backup folder). At this point, the Finder was working correctly. I ran EtreCheck, but got nothing in the report that I didn't already know. I then tried to open said backup folder by double clicking:
[image: Open newly created, erroneous backup folder]
At this point the beachball appeared and the Finder's Dock menu showed the following:
[image: Finder's Dock menu]

I ran EtreCheck again, but the report was identical to the previous one. Perhaps I need to pay for the upgrade get more information?

So, I shut down the Mac mini and reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM. I can't tell yet whether this has had an effect. When the machine had restarted, out of sheer cussedness I clicked on the erroneous backup folder again. This time it opened up normally and I could navigate the folder tree:
[image]

I also did "Enter Time Machine" (the interface for restoring files from TM) and could go back in time, including to folders that had previously caused the error above. I also manually started a TM backup which ran without any problem. I'll leave the machine for a while now and see what happens in the interim.

**Addendum 2**

Curiouser and curiouser... TM has failed again. Clicking on the last available backup folder has triggered the beachball in the Finder again. However, that folder is the one that TM successfully created after I manually started it this afternoon. I think this must have been the case also that I documented above.

So, when TM fails it does not create a folder. But an attempt to open the previous folder leads to the Finder beachball. I also conclude that SMC and NVRAM/PRAM reset had no effect, unfortunately.

**Addendum 3**

The problem seems to have gone away *again*. I wish I knew why because it has disappeared once before and then re-appeared after an OS upgrade. All I know is that I removed the disks from the enclosure - partly inspired by https://community.wd.com/t/error-occurred-while-creating-the-backup-folder/193764/40 - and ran First Aid over them individually. First Aid found nothing. I put the disks back into the enclosure, and since then there has been no problem.

Also, UniFi Controller has stopped generating spurious unreachability warnings.

**Addendum 4**

I forgot something important in Addendum 3: comments in the Western Digital community (see link above) suggested that WD disks have difficulty when waking from sleep. So I adjusted the Energy Saver settings on the Mac mini as follows:
[image: adjusted Energy Saver settings]
Perhaps this is the solution after all? Though making disks that won't wake from sleep seems rather odd these days...

Steve

Comment: I know this is not helpful PerSe but for what it is worth I still have Catalina on all 4 of my Macs. And a year ago Catalina was **still** problematic. Me, I'd consider how hard it would be to go back to Catalina. I know a lot of people have done the upgrade successfully but for me, the potential trouble is not worth the hassle.

Comment: @SteveChambers A serious consideration for me is completely decommissioning the Mac mini and using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu instead. I was hoping that by using the Mac mini for TM I could avoid the hassle of dealing with Samba.

Comment: Finder and DiskUtil are having issues -> don't worry about TM until that is fixed. Intermittent nature of issues suggest to me hardware issue with the StarTech, its drives or its cable.

Comment: You can download Etrecheck and scan your  System. It's a very good software.

Comment: I find it best in these cases to start narrowing down the issue. Now you could try this from different starting points, here are some ideas: Detach all devices, see if the problem with Finder persists. Then uninstall all programs you think may be causing problems. Reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM, use a different user account and boot into safe mode. If you have another drive (best with an SSD) try installing macOS there and see if problems persist.

Comment: As a data point, I have a 2018 Mini, and not had any problems upgrading to Big Sur (or to Catalina before that). I'm not sure that TM can backup directly to a RAID volume, can it? (Unless it's a NAS or other server.)

Comment: @Gilby “Finder and DiskUtil are having issues”: is this a summary of my situation or something you know about 11.3.1 in general?

Comment: @X_841 I can make the problem disappear by switching off TM or the StarTech. The program I think is causing problems is the Finder… :-)  I’ll try resetting SMC and NVRAM/PRAM.

Comment: @benwiggy The StarTech handles the RAID 1 stuff and appears to MacOS as a single volume. Also, TM does manage to work correctly for several hours before the problem occurs. However, I do suspect that the problem is somewhere in the interaction of TM, StarTech and Fonder.

Comment: I have added some new observations - based on this helpful feedback - to my question above.

Comment: I have added some more information as **Addendum 2**.

Comment: I have found this link (https://community.wd.com/t/error-occurred-while-creating-the-backup-folder/193764/40) which suggests contains various hints about the interaction of Apple software with WD disks. The disks in the StarTech are WD, so I shall see if this information helps.

Comment: "finder and disk util having problems" I was indicating that until that is fixed you won't get anywhere with TM. You need to do some hardware swapping to narrow down the problem: First, what happens if you replace the Startech with a different brand of disk and cable?

Comment: I've added what I hope will be my final update to the question above. The problem seems to have disappeared, but I don't know how or why.

Comment: @Gilby Thank you for your suggestions. I tried different disks when I was looking at the problem with StarTech support. The disks showed no problem. And after I removed them and put the original ones back in, there was also no problem any more. Until I upgraded the OS. That is more or less the situation I am in again now after I took the disks out yesterday and put them back in. I don't have a different cable to try, so I can't pursue that suggestion. But since it is working at the moment, I'm going to leave it and consider alternative solutions.

Comment: Can you restart your time machine backup?  I wonder if the changes to the OSX filesystem across iterations, concerning, hashes, read-only system folders, and different (likely?) private keys has borked the sym/hard-inking that time machine always seems to have issues with.

Comment: @pemby  Sorry, I don’t understand‍ How should I restart TM? Reboot the Mac? Or just disable/enable in System Prefs?

Comment: Actually, there was a change that I made after I scanned the disks with First Aid. It might be significant too (see Addendum 4 above).